# Automatic package recompilation on apt-get upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, source-code

Is it possible to achieve the following setup with apt-get on debian based distros, particulary Ubuntu:

I need to compile a package from source (like apt-get source ). Before compilation, I need to apply a patch to the source code. Then i compile and create the *.deb file and install it. Now all this is achievable with existing tools but what i need extra, is when I do apt-get update && apt-get upgrade I need the package I compiled from sources to redownload new sources (if there are any), apply the patch and if the patch succeeded, install the new version.

Is there a solution for this? (I know this is possible in Gentoo, but I would liek to find a solution for ubuntu first, if possible)
Thanks!

Comment: Something similar is done for DKMS kernel modules, is there a way to use that for normal packages? Please, suggest where is the best place to ask for a "feature request" for ubuntu or debian.